# JSON Parsing with JQuery from local directory

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have JSON data in my local folder in data/data.json

```
{"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Tomato Soup","type":"veg"},{"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Summer Salad","type":"veg"},{"category":"Main Course","menu_item":"Black Beans Chicken","type":"non-veg"},{"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Lentil Soup","type":"veg"},{"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Roasted Root Veg","type":"veg"},{"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Herbed Chicken Wings","type":"non-veg"},{"category":"Main Course","menu_item":"Barbecue Chicken Sandwich","type":"non-veg"},{"category":"Main Course","menu_item":"Pasta with Sausage","type":"veg"},{"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Roasted Shallot, Beet, Spinach","type":"non-veg"},{"category":"Starters","menu_item":"Sauteed Broccoli","type":"veg"},{"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Chicken Soup","type":"non-veg"}
```

I want to read this and I want to get the data, I am trying this code but I am not getting anything......

```
$.getJSON("data/data.json",
    function (data) {
       var i;
       for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
          $('<a href="">  <b>ITEM : </b>' + data.items[i].category +'</a><br>').appendTo(document.body);
       }
});
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have access to the local filesystem. You'll have to set up a webserver that can serve AJAX requests. You can try using Node.js (I've never used it but it might work), or use a LAMP/MAMP/WAMP setup (www.bitnami.com)

Comment: if by local directory you mean file folder, try using a different browser than chrome.  chrome bitches about it.  ff allows.

Comment: Did you check your error console? Your json data should have `[]` around it as it's an array. Also, your json data doesn't have an `items` property. With those two issues fixed, [it appears to work](http://jsfiddle.net/UyGxP)

Comment: shouldn't you check the data returned `length`? Or use the jQuery `$.map` function to just loop over the data?  Otherwise you are saying that there will always be 5 results in the dataset.

Comment: @JasonP .. what a brilliant question for you to answer!

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is incorrect. This seems to be an array of objects, they need to be wrapper between brackets:

INCORRECT

```
{"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Tomato Soup","type":"veg"}, ... ,{"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Chicken Soup","type":"non-veg"}
```

CORRECT

```
[{"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Tomato Soup","type":"veg"}, ... ,{"category":"Soups","menu_item":"Chicken Soup","type":"non-veg"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have access to the local filesystem. You'll have to set up a webserver that can serve AJAX requests. You can try using Node.js (I've never used it but it might work), or use a LAMP/MAMP/WAMP setup (www.bitnami.com)

Answer (score 0):

Mainly your Json is invalid, you should enclose the whole thing in [] if its an array of objects and {} if its an object with nested objects.

Check the syntax here: http://json.org/

After correcting it you should be able to get the data object.